# how to extract text using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Can you please show me how to extract the title text (Inna) using BeautifulSoup in this situation:

```
<div class="wallpapers-box-300x180-2 wallpapers-margin-2">
<div class="wallpapers-box-300x180-2-img"><a title="Inna" href="/photo.jpg" alt="Inna" width="300" height="188" /></a></div>
<div class="wallpapers-box-300x180-2-title"><a title="Inna" href="/wallpapers/inna/">Inna</a></div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many ways to locate the element in this case and it's difficult to tell which way would work for you better since we don't know the scope of the problem, how unique is the element and what do you know and can rely on.

The most practical approach here I think would be to use the following [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
for elm in soup.select('div[class^="wallpapers-box"] > a[href*=wallpapers]'):
    print(elm.get_text())
```

Here we check for the parent `div` element's class to start with `wallpapers-box` and find the direct `a` child element having `wallpapers` text inside the `href` attribute value.

Comment: Thanks, I just updated my question, they are more classes that start with wallpapers-box

Comment: @user1034127 and still the solution is valid.

Comment: It may be even shorter: for elm in soup.select('a[href="/wallpapers/inna/"]'):

Comment: @mmachine well, but less generic - not sure if `inna` is a given.